# I think I found a comment bug?

Tags: bug, status-declined

I recently posted a comment with 1 visible character. I could even do it with 0. I have a demo comment on this question to give you an idea of what I mean.

It exploits mathjax in order to use up characters which give no visible content.

In fact it's as easy as putting in

> $

Then

> {}{}{}{}{}{}{}

Then another

> $

..just without the separation (which if I never added it would've turned out like)

> ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Or as little {} you need in between the $s

**This same method can be applied to empty spoilers.. Or to bypass answer character limit**

*Before;*

> 

*After;*

> ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

*Although it may not seem like a big difference, the after picture don't have a space you could copy to clipboard if you were to do so.*

*First of all **Is this new?** Secondly **can it be fixed?***

Comment: ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: 1${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Okay, yeah, I think we get it with just the first few.

Comment: ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @V see? ${}{}{}$

Comment: [Question from Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245131/theres-a-loophole-for-the-15-characters-per-comment-requirement) . . . which is a duplicate of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240175/thousands-of-itty-bitty-comments-that-break-the-15-character-minimum-rule). And for the creative types, there's [this one with Unicode](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119614/using-unicode-zero-width-spaces-allows-all-space-comments).

Answer (score 6):

1. Is this new?

   No. This "bug" can be exploited on all Stack Exchange sites with MathJax.
2. Can it be fixed?

   Well, think about it. Which of these would you rather see?

   > I agree

   or

   > I agree -------

   or

   > I agree asdfghj

   or

   > ***`I agree`***

   There's really no reason to disallow *one* workaround when there are many, many others that people could use (ex. you could also pad your comment with [zero-width spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)).

Comment: I still think this should be patched, the point of a limit is to be a limit...

Comment: Ok.............

Comment: (point being: No reason to "fix" one workaround when people will just pad their comments in a million other ways.)

Comment: A comment including more than 3 repeated characters is highly unlikely, they can easily block that.

Comment: I see. asdfghjkl

Comment: @warspyking You probably don't want to place arbitrary restrictions because there's always edge cases. How about "`LLLLLLLLUURURDDDDDD` is shorter by 2 moves"?

Comment: @Doorknob Any more than 3 consonants in a row with no value after is obviously jibberish and can be blocked

Comment: @warspyking But then this very comment would be blocked by your patch

Comment: With no vowel* autocorrect changed to value lol. And how?

Comment: @warspyking "tch". Do you not realize that placing useless restrictions will do absolutely nothing to stop people who want to post a certain comment? "Ok. [padding padding]" All you're doing is preventing legitimate comments like "'Brrr' is an expression used when one is cold."

Comment: @Doorknob I do understand, but why is the restriction even there if it's so easily by passable?

Comment: @warspyking It exists simply to discourage comments like "+1" or "thanks" or "lol" or "I agree", not to *prevent* them outright.

Comment: Or to think of it another way, the restriction is to make sure that you can't post a frivolous comment like "+1" or "lol" _by accident_. Anyone who tries to circumvent the restriction will have to put some thought into doing so, and hopefully at some point in that thought process it occurs to them that maybe there's a reason they shouldn't be doing what they're trying to do. (The reason, of course, is not "short comments are bad" but rather "bad comments are bad".)

Comment: +1 ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: lol ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Door, I just found how easily abused this can be when combined with more tricks. Check out this now-deleted proof question I made; http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6450/

Comment: @warspyking Again: There's no reason to "fix" a workaround when there can be a million other ways to do the same. Could you name a practical, realistic situation in which this could be a problem?

Comment: @Door A new user finding it and posting random comments like "LOL!" Or "UMG". Besides, you have to admit, it's fairly easy to abuse.

Comment: @warspyking There are many, many other ways to post <15 char comments (I feel like we're going in circles here), and a user who continually posts noise or useless comments after being warned can be suspended.

Comment: @warspyking In a perfect world, it would be impossible to circumvent the character minimum. Here in the real world, the time it would take to fix all of those loopholes can be spent on far more valuable things. Anyone who deliberately and persistently exploits these loopholes can be dealt with on a one-off basis by moderators as needed.